# Translating windows bat file to linux shell script

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, batch-file

This is my exact batch file. I have tried to convert it doing some research online and get an error

> "Failed to execute child process "/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVal/TeachValLinuxShell" (No such file or directory)

```
echo off
cls
echo Running TeachVAL II...
set   path=%path%;/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
java -classpath comm.jar;Robot.jar;TeachVAL TeachVAL
cls
exit
```

This one is my attempt at translating.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +v
clear
echo "Running TeachVAL II..."
java -cp ".dir1;dir2;path/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/comm.jar;
path/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/Robot.jar;/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/TeachVAL"
clear
exit
```

Comment: did you check the path ? It said "no such file" after all.

Comment: I don't even see where you pass a class to `java` to run, only the class path setting.

Comment: The folder in your error message appears nowhere in your shell script code, which seems to indicate that either you've posted an incorrect error message or you've not included your actual code. Fix that issue, please.

Comment: My class is the TeachVal. I may not be passing that correctly

Comment: Maybe you should be asking/researching "how do I run java programs on Linux?" before you try to translate a batch file into a shell script.

Comment: @KenWhite what I did was make a shell script with this code.       #!/bin/bash
set +v
clear
echo "Running TeachVAL II..."
java -cp ".dir1;dir2;path/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/comm.jar;
path/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/Robot.jar;/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/TeachVAL"
clear
exit

Comment: When I double click the script shell file the system recognizes it is executable and allows me to press Execute and that is when the error appears. And I may be doing this all wrong as this is my first attempt at making a shell script.

Comment: The error message contains *LinuxShell*, which appears nowhere in your script.

Comment: There is one `TeachVAL` missing at the end of your java command line on Linux, compared to the Windows call. That's the one telling java what program it should actually run. However, as others have pointed out, your error message does not really fit the code you gave us, please make sure to copy/paste *exactly* input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Linux--life is good here, but there are a few things that work slightly differently, when compared to Windows.

One difference is that Windows uses semicolon (;) to separate entries in a list of paths, but Linux uses colons (:) for that purpose.

So, the Windows command:

```
java -classpath comm.jar;Robot.jar;TeachVAL TeachVAL
```

would correspond to this on Linux:

```
java -classpath comm.jar:Robot.jar:TeachVAL TeachVAL
```

In general, on Linux, semicolons are used to put multiple command lines into a single line.  Once you've learned that, I think you can then understand why:

```
java -cp .dir1;/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/TeachVAL
```

would be the same as:

```
java -cp .dir1
/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/TeachVAL
```

That would run java (with no class to be executed) and then try to run "/home/pi/Desktop/TeachVAL/TeachVAL" which can't be found.

There are many more differences to learn; here's a page that will help you get started:  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html